# CSS :hover class is affecting inner divs

Tags: html, css, hover, border, mousehover

```
.header-news-item {
   height:35px; 
   width:250px; 
   font-size:11px; 
   border: 2px solid #ddeeee; 
   float:left; 
   margin:0px 10px; 
   padding:7px; 
   padding-top: 5px;
   border-radius: 7px; 
   line-height:1.3; 
   background-color:#f9f9f9;

}

.header-news-item :hover {
    border: 2px solid #aadddd; 
    background-color:#f9f9f9;

}
```

I have a div element with border displayed. I want to change color of this border on hover event. So I have :hover pseudo-class defined in CSS. Problem is, that border of this div is not changed, but instead of that borders of inner divs are changed. Why is that? How could I fix it?

```
<div class="header-news-item">

    <div> title        </div>   <- 
    <div> subtitle     </div>   <- borders of these inner divs are changed
    <div> read more... </div>   <-

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a [descendant combinator](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#descendant-combinators) () between the `.header-news-item` class selector and the `:hover` pseudo-class selector. Remove it.

Comment: god, this is a malicious syntax error. I would never have though simple whitspace can make difference. thanks

Answer (score 3):

Remove the space between the .header-news-item and :hover in your CSS declaration so that it reads **.header-news-item:hover** instead of *.header-news-item :hover*.